# Eclipse not able to select Hybrid Mobile Engine for Hybrid Cordova application?

Tags: eclipse, cordova, eclipse-plugin, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I am using Eclipse Neon.3 and installed Thym plugin successfully. Now creating a new Project through New->Project->Hybrid Mobile(Cordova) Application project-> Project name as CordovaApp-> Next -> Select Hybrid Mobile Engine -> Here , unable to select any checkbox for Android, Windows tried download and search also. Here, wizard attached.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just click on Downloads Tab and select platform you preferred. If you have selected Android and selected android 6.3.0 cordova nightly download it and click on finish.
Now to see that is installed in your project. Right click on Project and select Properties, and click on Hybrid Mobile Engine you can able to view under the Platform selection. [image]